# jQuery and RegEx to extract a bit of information from URL Querystring

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, regex, querystringparameter

The query strings in my ASP.NET MVC are formatted like this: `http://mysite.com/blog/tag/my-tag`, instead of `http://mysite.com/blog/?tag=my-tag`, I need to extract the "my-tag" bit out of the URL, how could I accomplish that with jQuery on document loaded?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need to use jQuery for that:

```
var tag = window.location.href.split('/').pop();
```

Comment: or slightly faster: location.href.split('/').pop();

Comment: One quick question: How do I get the last two parameter, such as: `http://mysite.com/date/2011/01`, I need to grab the `2011` and `01`? Thanks again.

Comment: @Saxman `location.href.split('/')` will give you an array of the parts of the URL.  Use normal array manipulation techniques to get what you need.

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
document.location.toString().match('.*/(.*)$')[1]
```